# How to automatically add tags via capture template in org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I was trying to add a specific tag by default to my capture template. So that when the capture is complete, it looks like the following

```lisp
  * TODO                                  :customtag:
```

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/93990v/automatically_add_tag_to_capture_in_org_mode/) was the closest thread I was able to find. I was trying to figure out if there is a simpler way to do this, using just template expansions.

Comment: I don't think so, but the method in the link seems pretty simple.

Comment: @NickD  thanks for looking into this. Fortunately, I was able to solve this in a simpler way, I have added the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Yes, you are right (and I should have thought of that but I didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to use the function **org-set-tags**
The following capture template solves the above question

```lisp
(org-capture-templates
   '(("p" "Personal" entry
      (file "xyzz/location")
      "* TODO [Personal] %? %(org-set-tags \"personal\")
DEADLINE: %^t")))
```

Using **%()** around org-set-tags will ensure that the function is evaluated. You can replace **"personal"** with any tag of your choice.